# about separable equations when C is complex no

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Question:
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}= x[(1−y2)^1/2], \quad y(0)=0$$

right now I have that $f(x)=x$ and $g(y)=(1-y^2)^{1/2}$, then
\begin{align}
\int \frac 1{g(y)} \, dy&=\int x \, dx  \\
-y^{-1}(1-y^2)^{1/2}&=\frac{x^2}2+C
\end{align}
and solve this I get
$$y=\pm \frac 2{(x^2+4Cx^2+4C^2+4)^{1/2}}$$

and I stuck here. if we apply the boundary condition we have $\frac 1{(C^2+1)^{1/2}}=0$ 
so that $C= i$ or $-i$? what about $y$?

Comment: hi..dragon.. thx a lot for ur helping to make the question look so good. there's one problem that the question is dy/dx=bla bla without 4. thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is the equation $4\frac{dy}{dx}= x \sqrt{1−y^2}$ ?

Comment: no.. it is dy/dx=x[(1−y2)1/2] :) just without 4

Comment: Is the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}= x [1−y^2]^{1/2}$

Comment: yes exactly it is!

Comment: Then, you have a mistake in the integration.

Comment: emm.. can you tell me what the mistake is? cause I check and cannot find it

Comment: Where is $-y^{-1}(1-y^2)^{1/2}$ coming from ?

Comment: that is the answer i have to ∫1/g(y)dy.

Comment: I think that $\int \frac 1{g(y)} \, dy=sin^{-1}(y)$

Comment: you are right... thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome ! Glad you got it. Cheers :-)